# Need help on ffmpeg batch script

Tags: bash, shell, ffmpeg, directory

Trying to make a ffmpeg batch scripts that makes proress 422 proxy files from raw .mov files thats located in many subfolders. So far i got this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "drop source folder: "
read source

echo "drop destination folder: "
read des

find "$source" -name '*.mov' -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -vcodec prores -profile:v 0 -an "$des/${0%%.mov}.mov"' {} \;
exit;
```

But it doesn't output to the destination folder, only the source folder and ask for an overwrite - not what I want.

I guess it's a simple parameter error that maybe some of you can spot out?

All help is kindly appreciated!

Comment: this is a bash (Unix) script.Are you sure you mean batch (Windows) script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be my suggestion. Looks like this was follow-up from your previous thread.

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ] || {
    echo "You need Bash to run this script."
    exit
}

shopt -s extglob || {
    echo "Unable to enable exglob."
    exit 1
}

until
    read -erp "Drop source folder: " SOURCE
    [[ -d $SOURCE ]]
do
    echo "Drop source folder does not exist: $SOURCE"
    echo "You can abort this script by pressing CTRL-C."
done

until
    read -erp "Drop destination folder: " DES
    [[ -d $DES ]]
do
    echo "Drop destination folder does not exist: $DES"
    echo "You can abort this script by pressing CTRL-C."
done

while IFS= read -r FILE; do
    BASE=${FILE##*/}
    NOEXT=${BASE%.???}
    echo ffmpeg -i "$FILE" -vcodec prores -profile:v 0 -an "$DES/${NOEXT}.mov"  ## Remove echo if it's already correct.
done < <(exec find "$SOURCE" -type f -name '*.mov')  ## You could also use -iname '*.sh' instead to also match files like .MOV.
```

Notes: Using -e option for read is helpful to easily generate paths by pressing tab.

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error when running it:
make_proxy_wip02.sh: line 33: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
make_proxy_wip02.sh: line 33: `done < <(exec find "$SOURCE" -type f -name '*.mov')  ## You could also use -iname '*.sh' instead to also match files like .MOV.'

Comment: I don't see an error like that here. Please make sure you copy the script well and that it's in UNIX format. Try to edit it with VIM or similar editors and see if you're seeing ^M. Those should be not there. You could also convert the script to proper format with `dos2unix`. When everything's fine run `bash script.sh`.

Comment: sorry, my bad. Runned sh instead of bash... Thanks a lot for helping out! runs nice now!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to export the **`des`** variable.

In this kind of cases I always suggest to insert a "echo" just before the target command ("ffmpeg")

```
find "$source" -name '*.mov' -exec sh -c 'echo ffmpeg -i "$0" -vcodec prores -profile:v 0 -an "$des/${0%%.mov}.mov"' {} \;
```

This way you will see what you are trying to run